# How to strikeout "far fa eye" after click event in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I give eye open for show password. I want to strikeout when user click,. Here my code,

component.html

```
<i class="far fa-eye" 
      style="font-size: 22px; margin-left: -80px; cursor: pointer;" 
      id="togglePassword" (click) = "onclicktoggle()" ></i>
```

component.ts

```
onclicktoggle(){
    var x = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("password");
    if (x.type === "password") {
      x.type = "text";
    } else {
      x.type = "password";
    }
```

Thanks in advance,...
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't directly manipulate the DOM, let Angular do the work. Also, don't inline styles, write a css class.
2. For example:

Template:

```
<i class="fa another-custom-class"
   [class.fa-eye]="!isPasswordVisible"
   [class.fa-eye-slash]="isPasswordVisible"
   (click)="onclicktoggle()"></i>

<!-- Somewhere else... -->
<input [attr.type]="isPasswordVisible ? 'text' : 'password'">
```

TS:

```
isPasswordVisible = false;

onclicktoggle() {
    isPasswordVisible = !isPasswordVisible;
}
```

(Also, there's an Angular package with FontAwesome:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how `fa` works but try this way :

```js
showPassword = false;
```

```html
<i class="far fa-eye"
  [class.show]="showPassword"
  (click)="showPassword = !showPassword">
</i>
```

Comment: Sure. I will try it too. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

Replace the icon by this one

```
<i class="far fa-eye" *ngIf='!displayPassword'
  style="font-size: 22px; margin-left: -80px; cursor: pointer;" 
  id="togglePassword" (click) = "onclicktoggle()" ></i>

<i class="fa-solid fa-eye-slash" *ngIf='displayPassword'
  style="font-size: 22px; margin-left: -80px; cursor: pointer;" 
  id="togglePassword" (click) = "onclicktoggle()" ></i>
```

In your component, you should have something like

```
onclicktoggle(){
this.displayPassword = !this.displayPassword;
var x = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("password");
if (x.type === "password") {
  x.type = "text";
} else {
  x.type = "password";
}
```

Comment: Is there any value to using two `i` elements here instead of using `ngClass` to toggle which class/icon is displayed?

Comment: its worked. But eye icon not strikeout its gone. Thanks for your reply...

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution

```
    <span class="input-group-text" *ngIf="'password' != password.type">
      <i class="far fa-eye-slash cursor-pointer" aria-label="Show password" (click)="toggleVisible($event, password)"></i>
    </span>
    <span class="input-group-text" *ngIf="'password' == password.type">
      <i class="far fa-eye cursor-pointer" aria-label="Hide password" (click)="toggleVisible($event, password)"></i>
    </span>
```

where the second argument ( password ) of the toggleVisible method is the input reference ( #password )

```
<input type="password" [.. other props.. ] #password>
```

In your component ts

```
  toggleVisible($event: any, element: any) {
    element.type = 'text' == element.type ? 'password' : 'text'
  }
```